# How to expand a traineddata file in Tesseract?

Tags: tesseract

I want to add a new font to my language trained data file. I can build a new trained data file, and it works fine but is there any way that I could expand the old trained data file with the new one?

Comment: No, traineddata must be recreated each time. I've researched this as well, and it's just not supported.

Comment: oh that's sad. Do you know if they're planning to make that feature possible?

Comment: I doubt it. Think about it - from their point of view, they create the traineddata when creating a release version once or twice a year. So why bother? Google uses tesseract internally to index scanned documents in their search engine, and the fonts they use are fixed.

Comment: Wait, so all the traineddata files on the download site are NOT from the community? I thought they're contributed from people like us?

Comment: I doubt it, the official download will be prepared by the tesseract developers themselves. Other people are free to prepare their own traineddata for their own use. Not that I really know, I'm just guessing, mind you.

Comment: Btw I had created a tesseract trainer tool at the time, in case you need anything like that. It generates an image and box file from text you enter in a given font - https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-trainer/source/browse/

Answer (score 0):

I have seen here someone seems to do it... I am not able to check it since I am on Windows...
https://github.com/CavemanNinja/shell_scripts/blob/master/traintess.sh